# Highcharts chart is not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create chart when in success of ajax call success i give data to render chart to div it displays empty

My ajax Call

```
  var mWhereParam = { arrSelectedValues: arrSelectedValues };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "OssmWebService.asmx/FillChart",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(mWhereParam),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data1) {
            debugger;
         //   var ChartData = data1.d;


            var Graph = "line"

          Highcharts.setOptions({
              chart: {
                  type: Graph
              },

              credits: {
                  enabled: false
              },


              options3d: {
                  enabled: true,
                  alpha: 15,
                  beta: 15,
                  depth: 50,
                  viewDistance: 25
              },

              //title: { text: ''},
              //subtitle: { text:''},
              //xAxis: { categories: '' },
              yAxis: {
                  // reversed: true,
                  title: {
                      text: 'Rank'
                  },

                  labels: {
                      formatter: function () {
                          return this.value ;
                      }
                  },
              },
              xAxis: {
                  labels : {
                      useHTML: true,
                      formatter: function() {
                          return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                      }
                  }

              },
              plotOptions: {
                  series: {
                      animation: {
                          duration: 4000,
                      }
                  },
              },
              tooltip: {
                  headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
                  //animation: [true],
                  // pointFormat: '{point.x} Year: {point.y}'
              },
              //series: ''

              //legend: {
              //    layout: 'vertical',
              //    align: 'right',
              //    verticalAlign: 'middle',
              //    borderWidth: 0
              //},

          });

          debugger;
                var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart:{renderTo:'container1'},
                    //   title : {text :'<% = ViewState["DbTitle"].ToString() + " --  " + ViewState["DbSubTitle"].ToString() %>'},
                    title : data1.d



                });






            debugger;
            console.log(data1);
            console.log('success');
        }

    });


})
```

My Data which come in success of ajax

```
"{ text :'Basic Requirement'}, subtitle : { text : 'Basic Requirement'}, xAxis: { categories:['2010-2011','2011-2012','2012-2013','2013-2014','2014-2015','2015-2016','2016-2017']},
 series:[{ name: 'Basic Requirement-Oman', data: [24,20,15,13,19,29,42] , visible : true ,  dataLabels: {  enabled: true } },
{ name: 'Efficiency Enhancers-Oman', data: [48,45,45,39,49,63,63] } ] "
```

and My Html Div

It shows Like this on form
[image: Chart]

Please tell me what i am doing wrong is there is problem in data or what? cant figure out.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug like this. If you can make a `jsfiddle` that would be very helpful. Otherwise, try to take a basic line chart example from the Highcharts example page. Make sure that works, then tweak it until it looks like the way you want.

Comment: Your code is very confusing, and I am not seeing anything that actually sets the series properties in the chart options. Is there some part of your code missing?

Comment: Also, in your JSON, this: `"{ text :'Basic Requirement'}` should presumably be: `"title: { text :'Basic Requirement'}`

Comment: series properties are comming in json @jlbriggs

Comment: @MussaibSiddiqui, he means that you never actually set your chart's series to anything coming from your ajax call so there is nothing to plot.

Comment: @MussaibSiddiqui right - but your code doesn't do anything with it that I can see. It doesn't do any good for the JSON to be there if you don't access it.

Comment: @jlbriggs  you can see below i am giving my json data to title property

Comment: OK, well what do you expect the library to do with a set of data applied to the title property of the chart?? I can see now that is why you are missing the `title: {` portion of your JSON, but this is a very flawed way to approach this, and as you can clearly see, does not work.  You should parse your JSON for the appropriate objects, and supply them appropriately to the chart.